# NHibernate w/ Fluent - No persister for: [class]

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate for the first time but wanted to be able to avoid config files if possible, by using NHibernate Fluent. I've got a project setup and I'm trying simply query for an adress object using the following

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.Is("[ConnectionStringHere")))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<RedSand.Models.Data.Mapping.AddressMapping>());

    var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

    var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    session.Get<Address>(new Guid("A8B9BA39-425D-4AE6-A72E-00216ABC87C4"));
}
```

However it's blowing up on the `Get<T>()` method with an error complaining about there being no persister. My address classes are below.

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public Guid CityId { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public bool DefaultAddress { get; set; }
    public bool TermAddress { get; set; }
    public string SuiteNumber { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public int Accuracy { get; set; }
}

public class AddressMapping : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMapping()
    {
        Table("tblAddress");
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(a => a.AddressId).Column("AddressID").GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(a => a.StreetAddress).Column("Address").Length(100);
        Map(a => a.CityId).Column("CityID");
        Map(a => a.PostalCode).Length(50);
        Map(a => a.DefaultAddress);
        Map(a => a.TermAddress).Default("0");
        Map(a => a.SuiteNumber).Column("SuiteNo").Length(50);
        Map(a => a.Latitude);
        Map(a => a.Longitude);
        Map(a => a.Accuracy);
    }
}
```

I'm using an existing database so try to ignore the funky table structure/naming.

Am I missing something here? Can any of you see something that would explain why it's complaining about a No persister?

Comment: I tried replicating this, and cannot get it to fail. Are you sure you do not have two separate "Address" classes defined?

Comment: Maybe I should do the same thing you did and create a new application and try to replicate my own error, maybe something got mixed up in my current project with references or something? Would that cause the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly in `AddFromAssemblyOf` should be a mapped class, not a mapping file. Is Address in a different assembly than AddressMapping? Try changing it to `AddFromAssemblyOf<YourNamespace.Address>`.

Comment: The namespace for the `Address` class is already fully resolved in the call to 'AddFromAssemblyOf<T>()' so I'm positive it's not a problem resolving the namespace. I used to have it adding the entire assembly but reduced it to the one `Address` class in an effort to remove complexity. The code I'm using to test this is in a separate project yes, it's the test project that the MVC App created, however I only moved this to the test project after I got the same error in the MVC application.

Comment: Crap! I just noticed what you meant. Not the call to `AddFromAssemblyOf<T>()`, but to fully resolve it on the `Get<T>()` method. Turns out I had an Address class defined in another reference I didn't realize and it was defaulting to that one instead of the one I had created in in this project. I hate little bugs like this, sometimes it just needs a second set of eyes to sort it out.

Comment: Actually I did mean the `AddFromAssemblyOf<T>` method. But I'm glad it pointed you in the right direction.